# tlmgr: action not allowed in system mode: ... (texlive)

Tags: texlive, tlmgr, macos

I made a fresh install of texlive using homebrew on a macbook that have sat unused for about a year. I removed all previous tex distributions I found, both for the (sole) user and systemwide.

Now I am just trying to install biblatex and biber to compile my works.

However using `tlmgr`, I get the following error messages:

```
$ tlmgr install biber
tlmgr: action not allowed in system mode: install

$ sudo tlmgr update --self --all
tlmgr: action not allowed in system mode: update
```

I managed to install biblatex on my local tree with

```
$ tlmgr --usermode install biblatex
```

but when I do it for biber, I get

```
$ tlmgr --usermode install biber
query_ctan_mirror: Programs not set up, trying wget
cannot contact mirror.ctan.org, returning a backbone server!
tlmgr: package repository http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: pubkey missing)
tlmgr: package biber is not relocatable, cannot install it in user mode!
```

(I don't know why the servers are acting weird)

`sudo` does not help.

In summary, I cannot make `tlmgr` work without any `--usermode` option, but I cannot install `biber` in usermode.
I am lost, I don't understand why tlmgr cannot run properly in system mode in the first place.
Any ideas?

Thank you everyone :)

Comment: Check with `alias tlmgr`, on my system it was aliased to `/usr/share/texmf-dist//scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl --usermode` -- which is why it never went into system mode.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but I was looking for `update` and `option` commands.

Reading man page (`tlmgr --help`) I found this:

> "tlmgr" reads two configuration files: one is system-wide, in
> "TEXMFSYSCONFIG/tlmgr/config", and the other is user-specific, in
> TEXMFCONFIG/tlmgr/config". The user-specific one is the default for the
> "conf tlmgr" action. (Run "kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFSYSCONFIG" or "...
> TEXMFCONFIG ..." to see the actual directory names.)

At `TEXMFSYSCONFIG/tlmgr/config`, I found that `config` file lists the action allowed to be taken system-wide with `tlmgr`

I edited that file appending `update,option` and I was then able to issue both

```
$ tlmgr option ...
$ tlmgr update --list
```

In your case, you should add `install` and you should be able to install `biber`

Note also that, if you wish to update tlmgr you have to manually create backup folder.
Just issue `tlmgr update --self` and take a look at the output.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `tlmgr`, don't install it via homebrew. Download the MacTex package from its homepage instead.

As you can see here

https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4226#discussioncomment-5008376

the maintainer of the `texlive` formula (homebrew package) expressly blocs the user from using `tlmgr`.

**Footnote:** If you are a Mac user, there is no advantage for using the homebrew version of `texlive` except for the ease of installation. If the ease of installation isn't important to you, the only raison d'être of the homebrew version is for it to be depended upon by other packages ("formulae" in the homebrew parlance). That is, if you install a homebrew package that depends on `texlive`, the latter is automatically installed as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

`biber` is a Perl backend for biblatex, not really a true LaTeX package. It can be installed using Homebrew.

`brew install biber`